# Neural network weight initialization: symmetry of distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, machine-learning, neural-networks

In He initialization by He et al. [1], we have $y_{l-1} = w_{l-1}^T x_{l-1} + b_{l-1}$ where $y_{l-1}$, $w_{l-1}$, $x_{l-1}$ are vector valued random variables associated with layer $l$.

Here we let $w_{l-1}$ to have a symmetric distribution around zero and $b_{l-1}=0$. With this condition, the authors said that $y_{l-1}$ has mean 0 and has symmetric distribution around zero.

I understand $E[y_{l-1}] = 0$ because $E[y_{l-1}] = \sum_{i}^{} E[w_{(l-1),i} x_{(l-1),i}] = \sum_{i}^{} E[w_{(l-1),i}] E[x_{(l-1),i}] = 0$ using the independence of $w_{l-1}$ and $x_{l-1}$.

But I don't understand why $y_{l-1}$ has the symmetric distribution around zero. How can I show this?

[1] He et.al: http://arxiv.org/abs/1502.01852

Comment: Are $w_{l-1}$ and $x_{l-1}$ independent?

Comment: Yes. They are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $y>0$ and $x$, note that
\begin{align*}
 P(Y \geq y|x)
 &= P(W^{t}x \geq y|x) 
 & \text{W independent of X} \\
 &= P((-W^{t})x \leq -y|x) \\
 &= P(W^{t}x \leq -y|x) 
 & \text{W is symmetric around 0} \\
 &= P(Y \leq -y|x)
\end{align*}
Conclude that
\begin{align*}
 P(Y \geq y) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P(Y \geq y|x)f_{X}(x)dx} \\
             &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P(Y \leq -y|x)f_{X}(x)dx} 
             = P(Y \leq -y)
\end{align*}
Conclude that $P(Y \geq y) = P(Y \leq -y)$, that is,
$Y$ is symmetric around $0$.

Comment: For law of total probability step, do you mean this $\mathbb{P} \left(Y \ge y \right) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P} \left(Y \ge y|X = x \right) f_X(x) dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P} \left(Y\le -y|X = x \right) f_X(x) dx = \mathbb{P} \left(Y \le -y \right)$?

Comment: Indeed. I added this passage to the solution.